# Exclude files in coverstory while checking code coverage

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage, coverstory

I just tried to check the code coverage using cover story in Xcode 4.6 and I am able to generate .gcda and .gcno files and check the overall and individual coverage of each file.

But, I want to exclude some classes in the cover story while checking the code coverage. I am not able to do so as it is again covering all the classes. I tried to exclude files from:

CoverStory->Preferences->SDK Files ........and included the file I want to exclude. But it is not working.

I followed this link : http://iosunittesting.com/configuring-coverstory/

Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: I am using the code coverage for my ios projects in xcode 4.6. I am having the same issue and wanted to exclude some of the classes. Any clue on this? Also how can I get the overall code coverage, not individually for each file but the overall coverage for all the files? Thanks!

Comment: While using cover story, you can simply include the whole folder in which your project's .gcda and .gcno files are saved. In this way, after executing, it will show the overall coverage as well as the individual coverage for your code.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late but I just wanted to let you know that I got the solution. The problem that I was facing was probably due to the Xcode corruption. So, as soon as I reinstalled the Xcode, it started working fine and I was able to check the code coverage of the individual files through cover story.